# Include finding all the Same String Values in a Column in existing VBA script

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner at VBA to start off. I have an existing VBA script(written by someone else) that compares rows between two workbooks having two sheets each. I would compare the rows from both sheets of one workbook against the other. Now due to a change in requirement, I need to get rows with a specific string value in one of the columns first and then compare these rows with rows of the other workbook that have the same string value for that specific column. I want to know how to incorporate finding those specific values from the rows first into the existing script, then do comparison and then output those rows into a new Excel File highlighted in yellow or any color.

This is the existing script code I tried but need to change :

```
Sub CompareTwoWorkbooks()
 
  Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wsMatch As Boolean
 
  'Open a file dialog to select workbooks (optional)
 
  'Set each of the 2 workbooks to object variables
  Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
  Set wb2 = Workbooks("Example_Excel_file.xlsx")
 
 
    'Loop through worksheets
    For Each ws1 In wb1.Worksheets
      wsMatch = False
      For Each ws2 In wb2.Worksheets
        If ws1.Name = ws2.Name Then
          wsMatch = True
          'Compare the 2 worksheets
          For Each cell In ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            If cell.Value <> ws2.Range(cell.Address).Value Then
                cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
 
            End If
          Next cell
          Exit For
        End If
      Next ws2
      If wsMatch = False Then ws1.Tab.Color = vbYellow
    Next ws1
 
End Sub
```

Sample Data :

```
Compliant:
     yes
     yes
     yes
     no
     yes
     no
     yes
     no
     yes

For the above column, I need to get rows that have "no" in the column. Compare these rows with rows in another workbook that have "no" for the compliant column. Get the difference and put it in a new excel workbook.
```

Since I dont have VBA experience, I am having difficulty figuring out how to change it to get those specific rows and then do comparison and output them.

Comment: `I need to get rows with a specific string value in one of the columns first and then compare these rows with rows of the other workbook that have the same string value for that specific column.` Please clarify the meaning with sample data in your post. It's helpful to understand your case.

Comment: Hi, I have added a sample example. I hope this helps clarify what I require.